# form does not submit and the validation not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, validation

i am new to javascript , i have created a registration form but it does not submits and the validation is not working . i could not know what is wrong in the code .
the validation function is to check whether the input contains only alphabets

**file.html**

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/inscrption_form.css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
       <script  type="text/javascript"src="/js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
     <div class="mainheader">
      <div class="logo">
        <h2> A </h2>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>


    <form id="forme" onsubmit="return valider()">
        <table>
            <tr>
         <td colspan="2" align="center">
                 <h1> Form </h1>
             </tr>
        <tr>.. </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>*Nom</td>
            <td><input type="text" placeholder = "Sara" id = "nom"maxlength="25"  required></td>
            <small id="error2">errr </small>
        </tr>
       <tr>.. </tr>
        <tr>.. </tr>
       <tr>.. </tr>
         <tr>.. </tr>
       <tr>.. </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <button type="submit"  value="Envoyer">sign up </button>

                <button type="reset"  value="Annuler">Annuler</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
    function valider()
{
    // nom test 
    var input = document.getElementById('nom');
    var alphabets = /^[A-Za-z]+$/ ;
    if(input.value.match(alphabets))
      { 
        return true ;
    }else{
     document.getElementById('error2').innerText ="only alphabets  "   
        return false ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console when submitting the form? Do you see any calls in the network panel?

Answer (score 0):

I put your code in a snippet and it works fine. The validation is ok and the form submits to the same url. Maybe you want to set the action attribute to the form and sending with method="POST".

```js
  function valider()
{
    // nom test 
    var input = document.getElementById('nom');
    var alphabets = /^[A-Za-z]+$/ ;
    if(input.value.match(alphabets))
      { 
        return true ;
    }else{
     document.getElementById('error2').innerText ="only alphabets  "   
        return false ;
    }
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/inscrption_form.css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
       <script  type="text/javascript"src="/js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
     <div class="mainheader">
      <div class="logo">
        <h2> A </h2>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>


    <form id="forme" onsubmit="return valider()">
        <table>
            <tr>
         <td colspan="2" align="center">
                 <h1> Form </h1>
             </tr>
        <tr>.. </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>*Nom</td>
            <td><input type="text" placeholder = "Sara" id = "nom"maxlength="25"  required></td>
            <small id="error2">errr </small>
        </tr>
       <tr>.. </tr>
        <tr>.. </tr>
       <tr>.. </tr>
         <tr>.. </tr>
       <tr>.. </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <button type="submit"  value="Envoyer">sign up </button>

                <button type="reset"  value="Annuler">Annuler</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```